# Must provide Source with graphql API call in AWS amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, resolver, amplifyjs

I have got an error during a graphql API call in AWS amplify

I import the queries like (just like in the documentation with *):

```
import * as queries from '../graphql/queries';
```

This is my API request where I receive the error (Must provide Source):

```
const data = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(queries.nearbyZVL, {filter: filter}));
```

And in the same file another API request like below is working correctly:

```
const result = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(queries.getProfile, { id: cognitoUserId }));
```

The nearbyZVL is a custom query and resolver in AWS appsync. In the appsync console the query is working fine!

Some help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it is not generated in codegen - to create custom resolvers, did you manually edit on appsync console, or adding files under `/amplify/backend`? For the latter, it should codegen. If you did the former, consider do the latter.

In your case, you can simply do below:

```js
const GetNearbyZVL = `...` // the query that works in appsync console

const data = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(GetNearbyZVL, {filter: filter}));
```